# Can apple reject application if we using constraints not according to HIG

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I want to know that I have applied the constraint in my application for iOS. I have mentioned the distance that between view1 from bottom will be 14. I have listening to the of the lectures at standford about the constraint. He said apple will reject the application if we specify the number in the constraint. The video name is "8. Autolayout and Navigation (January 31, 2013).mp4". Can anybody please verify that this is true or not.

Here is the screenshot of the video:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: No screenshot. And please explain your whole questions instead of pointing to a video; don't expect any of us to look it up for you.

Comment: please edit your answer so everybody can understand what you mean and provide the screenshot you were talking about

Comment: Here is the link of the URL  http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=24fmcl1&s=5. Sorry for the confusion. My question in short is will apple reject my application if I define a constraint with constant number.